# React App Not Rendering Cannot Find Module "./"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core, redux

I'm working on a legacy project which consists of an WEB API build in ASP.NET Core which works as backend, and the data received by that API is rendered in the frontend with React.

When I run the frontend, the page first loads some elements but instantly I get this message error.

```
webpackContextResolve
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/src/images/productos /^/.*$:17
webpackContext
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/src/images/productos /^/.*$:12

Card
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/src/components/home/card/Card.js:7
   4 | 
   5 | const Card = props => {
   6 |   const {data} = props;
>  7 |   const logo = require("../../../images/productos/" + data.urlImage);
   8 |   const divisa = "€";
   9 | 
  10 |   return (

 renderWithHooks
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react- 
dom.development.js:14803
mountIndeterminateComponent
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react- 
dom.development.js:17482
beginWork
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react- 
dom.development.js:18596
HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react- 
dom.development.js:188
invokeGuardedCallbackDev
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react- 
dom.development.js:237
invokeGuardedCallback
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react- 
dom.development.js:292
beginWork$1
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react- 
dom.development.js:23203
performUnitOfWork
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react- 
dom.development.js:22154
workLoopSync
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react- 
dom.development.js:22130
performSyncWorkOnRoot
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react- 
dom.development.js:21756
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react- 
dom.development.js:11089
unstable_runWithPriority
runWithPriority$1
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react- 
dom.development.js:11039
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react- 
dom.development.js:11084
flushSyncCallbackQueue
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react- 
dom.development.js:11072
batchedUpdates$1
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react- 
dom.development.js:21862
notify
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/node_modules/react- 
redux/es/utils/Subscription.js:19
Subscription.notifyNestedSubs
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/node_modules/react- 
redux/es/utils/Subscription.js:92
Subscription.handleChangeWrapper
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/node_modules/react- 
redux/es/utils/Subscription.js:97
dispatch
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/node_modules/redux/es/redux.js:222
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux- 
toolkit.esm.js:563
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/node_modules/redux-thunk/es/index.js:11
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux- 
toolkit.esm.js:409
dispatch
C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/node_modules/redux/es/redux.js:638
 ▲ 24 stack frames were expanded.
 (anonymous function)
  C:/Users/ruchi/Desktop/QROrders/FrontAppWebPhoneOrder/src/modules/home/actions.js:57
   54 | fetch('/productTypes', {config})
   55 |   .then(response => response.json())
   56 |   .then(productType => {
 > 57 |     dispatch({
   58 |       type: SHOW_PRODUCT_TYPE_RESPONSE,
   59 |       productType
   60 |     });
```

Sorry for putting so much messages, but I'm really lost with react and I don't know how to solve the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Where is the error mesage? Did you already try `npm install` in the folder that contains the package.json file?

Comment: are you using redux-thunk for API calls on the front-end?